# Error:(28, 58) error: incompatible types: Object cannot be converted to Address

Tags: android, geocode

I am creating an app which would display latitutes and longitudes from a given string

```
Geocoder geocoder = new Geocoder(context, Locale.getDefault());
String result = null;
try {
  List addressList = geocoder.getFromLocationName(locationAddress, 1);
  if (addressList != null && addressList.size() > 0) {
     Address address = addressList.get(0);
     StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
     sb.append(address.getLatitude()).append("\n");
     sb.append(address.getLongitude()).append("\n");
     result = sb.toString();
  }
}
```

and this exception is occuring:

```
Error:(28, 58) error: incompatible types: Object cannot be converted to Address
The List addressList is storing address type values .
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because you use a raw type, which is `List`. You need to use `List<Address>`.

When the following code is called:

```
Address address = addressList.get(0);
```

It returns an **Object** from the following code:

```
List addressList = geocoder.getFromLocationName(locationAddress, 1);
```

Then it will give an error because `addressList.get(0)` is an Object which isn't an **instanceof** Address.

Read more about raw type: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2770692/4758255

Comment: thanks, and I would like to ask if 
`Address address = (Address)addressList.get(0);` is used and data type remains raw, what would be the difference...

Comment: That is a downcasting which will fail and throw a `ClassCastException` because the actual object type from `addressList.get(0)` is an **Object**. **Object** is not an **Address** so we cannot cast it to an **Address**.